# LeakCanary is currently disabled caused by leakcanary.LeakAssertions was found in classpath

Tags: java, android, kotlin, leakcanary

I have been trying to add LeakCanary to my codebase.

I've read the instructions from the [Getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) where I also found out that [LeakCanary has a test environment detection](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/#leakcanary-test-environment-detection) and I should add the following to my codebase if I see the message `LeakCanary is currently disabled`

```
<resources>
  <string name="leak_canary_test_class_name">assertk.Assert</string>
</resources>
```

Which in my case is the below as I don't use AssertK

```
<resources>
  <string name="leak_canary_test_class_name">org.assertj.core.api.Assertions</string>
</resources>
```

The problem I'm running into now is that the message looks like the following.

```
LeakCanary is currently disabled: test class leakcanary.LeakAssertions was found in classpath.
LeakCanary: No heap analysis performed
```

Does anyone know what is the issue now?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an explanation as to why, but you may be able to work around the issue by writing an empty class that you include in your test classpath, and use that class for test environment detection.